# bind can I use hostnames in also-notify instead of IP?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I'm using my VPS provider's DNS servers as a slave, and to send them notifies, I use the `also-notify` function. They're making changes to the IP scheme of their DNS, which means I need to update my `also-notify`, which is fine, but I'm looking to future proof.

Today I have `also-notify { 1.2.3.4; 4.5.6.7 }`

Could I do this instead? `also-notify { ns1.my-vps; ns2.my-vps }`

Comment: Look at [the `masters` clause](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/masters.html).

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I'm running a master DNS server, want to send notifies to slaves using hostname, not IP. This still looks like it's IP. From what I'm reading the IP is a requirement, so I don't think I'm able to do hostname

Comment: Is the slave named in the zone's NS RRs? If it is, then it should be receiving notifies already, and if it isn't, the whole exercise seems somewhat pointless. `also-notify {}` is for hosts which *aren't* named in zone NS RRs.

Comment: Michael is correct, you should be using `NS` records for this purpose. Refer to [Why don't NS records contain IP addresses?](http://serverfault.com/a/764957/152073). That said, it still doesn't get around the potential need to update glue records with your registrar. (i.e. if you had to provide these IPs to your registrar's web interface, they still need to be changed)